# Android Proper Layout Design

Tags: android, android-layout

I've looked around the internet for about a bit trying to find some guides on XML design.

So far I've found that the best design is to keep the layout "flat", meaning keeping layout nesting to a minimum.

Basically I have four of the layout below stacked on top of each other.  I have no plans of adding more than 4.  The only thing that differs between each is the image in the simple_detail_image.  The options that I've found are using `<include>` for each item and then programmatically changing the images.

Is this the best practice or is there something more practical?

Another option I've explored is making a `ListView` and populating it with these but that seemed like overkill.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="@drawable/shape_rounded"
              android:padding="4dp"
              android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/simple_detail_image"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/simple_detail_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:text="Hi"/>


    <Space
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/chevron_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/chevron_horizontal_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_chevron_gray"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use `ListView` if the whole thing is repeating

Comment: Wait, where are the 4 layouts? I see one with 4 views. Hence nesting here is zero.

Comment: I do not have the reputation to post a picture representing it.  The view I show above is what I want to stack 4 of. When I mention nesting, I'm referring to using as few 'LinearLayouts' or their equivalents as possible. The point of my post is to find the **Proper** way to arrange the above code into 4 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify the whole thing using a single TextView in place of a whole layout, no images and no container.

Since a TextView can contain different compound drawables at the same time.
For instance:

```
android:drawablePadding="4dp"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_chevron_gray"
```

You can include the 4 TextViews in your outer (vertical) container and you are done.

Then, in code, to change the drawableLeft:

```
//public void setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds (int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
public void setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds (R.drawable.your_left_drawable_1, 0, R.drawable.ic_chevron_gray, 0);
```

This will keep your layout super flat and efficient.